# PHP coleta da dados e inserindo dados mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando coletar dados da última seção inserida via PHP no MySQL, que mostre na tela o último `(id, Nome, Idade)` etc. da `query` inserida.

pagina apos inclusão deve aparecer esse campos abaixo da pagina selecione

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Selecione</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php

       //niciando a conexão com o banco de dados
       $cx = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");

       //selecionando o banco de dados
       $db = mysqli_select_db($cx, "itil");


        //criando a query de consulta à tabela criada
        $sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT * FROM glpi_change_new") or die(
         mysqli_error($cx) //caso haja um erro na consulta
        );

        //pecorrendo os registros da consulta.
        if($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql), === TRUE)  {
           $last_id = $aux->insert_id;
           echo "<h3>GMUD incluida com sucesso! GMUD n°: </h3>" . $last_id;

           echo "-----------------------------------------<br/>";
           echo "ID:" ; $aux["idglpi_change_new"] . "<br />";
           echo "Nome:" . $aux["tNome"] . "<br />";
           echo "Email:" . $aux["tEmail"] . "<br />";
           echo "Tel: " . $aux["tTel"] . " ";
           echo " Cel: " . $aux["tCel"] . "<br />";
           echo "Unid: " . $aux["tUnid"] . " ";
           echo " Departamento: " . $aux["tDepartamento"] . "<br />";
           echo "Data da Execução: " . $aux["tDate"] . "<br />";
           echo "Cliente: " . $aux["tCliente"] . "<br />";
           echo "Detalhe da origem: " . $aux["t_dtorigem"] . "<br />";
           echo "Mudança: " . $aux["tMudança"] . "<br />";
           echo "Descrição da Mudança: " . $aux["tDescmud"] . "<br />";
           echo "Risco Execução: " . $aux["tRiscExec"] . "<br />";
           echo "Controle de Backup: " . $aux["tContrback"] . "<br />";
           echo "Tempo de Recuperação: " . $aux["tTempodeRec"] . "<br />";
           echo "Plano de ação para Execução: " . $aux["tPlanodeacaopexec"] . "<br />";
           echo "Urgencia porque: " . $aux["tUrgpq"] . "<br />";

    ?>
```

Comment: Posta o seu código, fica mais fácil te ajudar se você postar um [Exemplo Mínimo e Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AndreGusmao Obrigado!!  feito alteração conforme seu report

Comment: Não seria apenas fazer um ORDER BY idglpi_change_new DESC LIMIT 1? Aí traria apenas o ultimo resultado da tabela sempre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que nesse caso, pelo que entendi é apenas ordenar sua busca a limita-lá, retornando sempre o ultimo registro da tabela:

```
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM glpi_change_new ORDER BY idglpi_change_new DESC LIMIT 1";
    $sql = mysqli_query($cx, $qry  or die(
             mysqli_error($cx) //caso haja um erro na consulta
            );
```

Comment: Show!! obrigado! @arllondias